# Meta description for index page not appearing in laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel, metadata

I have 3 sets of URL (index page, detail page and review page). For detail page and review page, meta description are appearing but not in index page.

```
@if(strpos(Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->uri(), 'reviews') !== false && isset($movie_review->description))
    <meta name="description" content="{{isset($movie->title)?'Watch '.$movie->title.' online. '.$movie_review->description}}"> 
@elseif(strpos(Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->uri(), 'detail') !== false && isset($movie->overview))
    <meta name="description" content="{{isset($movie->title)?'Watch '.$movie->title.' online. '.$movie->overview}}"> \ 
**@elseif(strpos(Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->uri(), 'index') !== false)
    <meta name="description" content="{'This is index page description!'}">** 
@endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `index` with `/` as given below:

```php
@elseif(strpos(Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->uri(), '/') !== false)
   <meta name="description" content="This is index page description!">
@endif
```